# Passing multiple parameters through the image URL property

Tags: c#

> I need to pass multiple parameters dynamically to my ascx file
>   through the image url    property.
>       I tried `<%# "ImageHandler.ashx?uid="+ Eval("PlantId")  %>`. Similarly, how can I send three parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<%# "ImageHandler.ashx?uid="+ Eval("PlantId") +"&param2="+ Eval("Param2") +"&param3="+ Eval("Param3") %>`